# .NET Maui starts iOS simulator but does not deploy app

Tags: ios-simulator, maui

My app runs fine on the Android simulator, but when I choose a iOS simulator it starts it up but does not deploy/run the app on the simulator.

The log file is pretty inconclusive:

```
Start device request:
Current State: Unknown
UUID: 8F4ABBAE-84B1-4435-992C-9936F50CC66B
Name: iPhone 14 Pro
Platform: iOS
Version: 16.2
Device state changed:
UUID: 8F4ABBAE-84B1-4435-992C-9936F50CC66B
State: Starting
Device state changed:
UUID: 8F4ABBAE-84B1-4435-992C-9936F50CC66B
State: Started
SizeForScreen:
Monitor: 0,0,1920,1032
Scale: 1,1
Source: 1179,2556
extraHeight: 84
Connection state changed:
State: Disconnected
Connection state changed:
State: Connecting
SSH Connect:
target: 192.168.1.108
Using SSH pass phrase
SSH connected
Connection state changed:
State: SshConnected
Connection state changed:
State: CheckingServer
Connection state changed:
State: SettingUpServer
Starting server
[Server] ready:49378
Connection state changed:
State: Connecting
Connection state changed:
State: CheckingServer
Connection state changed:
State: Connected
Device state changed:
    UUID: 8F4ABBAE-84B1-4435-992C-9936F50CC66B
State: Starting
Device state changed:
    UUID: 8F4ABBAE-84B1-4435-992C-9936F50CC66B
State: Started
```

And no errors in the output window. Visual Studio 2022 CE 17.4.3 and Mac OS Ventura 13.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 14.2 is being worked on and it's not supported yet. And from the release note of [Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#1743--visual-studio-2022-version-1743), we can find that :

```
Adds Xcode 14.1 support for .NET for iOS, tvOS, macOS, Mac Catalyst.
```

So, you can try to deploy your app to another emulator with a lower version.

Comment: I have downgraded my XCode version from 14.2 to 14.1 build is successful but still cant see the deployed app in the simulator any work around for this or other settings that needs to followed. Visual studio 2022 For Mac and Visual Studio 2022 preview for Mac , Macbook Air OS Ventura